# Showing data as percentage values on Pie Chart. (Using RDLC)

Tags: c#, rdlc

I am using RDLC reporting for showing pie chart in my C#.net application.
I need to show values in percentage form on the pie chart. 
What expression should be used in order to show desired data? 
Please help me...

Answer (score 4):

right click on the labels of the chart, In the general tab choose #PERCENT for the label data

Comment: Answer not validated but i had the same problem and this works

Answer (score 2):

To put the % value on each pie chart slice do this (as shown [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239373%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)):

1. On the design surface, right-click on the pie and select Show Data Labels. The data labels should appear within each slice on the pie chart.
2. On the design surface, right-click on the labels and select Series Label Properties. The Series Label Properties dialog box appears.
3. Type #PERCENT for the Label data option.

Result:

[image]

If you are dealing with mutliple data fields feeding your pie, check out [this](http://www.morrenth.com/report-designer-rdlc-pie-chart-data-labels-for-multiple-data-fields.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Before you right click on the pie chart fill the data fields and series fields first  else you will not see show data labels.