# Pie Chart control in C# .net 4.0 framework

Tags: charts

I want to show the value and label in the legend of pie chart.

for Example :
xyz(1) abc (5)

and this data should be fetched from database via query.
and after that i need to calculate the  from the legend value in percent and show in the pie chart.

PFA image[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2jIp.png)

Please help me how can i do it.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Showing data as percentage values on Pie Chart. (Using RDLC)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/785770/showing-data-as-percentage-values-on-pie-chart-using-rdlc)

Comment: I am not using RDLC .